# Socket.Send has a delay?

Tags: c#, sockets

I am building an application and sending data back to the other side,

In my application, I have:

`System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Send(byte[])` function.

My customer told me that there is `530 ms delay` of receiving this packet. However, I have logged every where until: `System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Send(byte[])`

I measured that it took about 15ms to get to send an array from Socket. My customer advised me to check:

- To flush after sending, but I dont see a `flush function` in Socket?
- Fill up the data buffer before sending out otherwise, if the data is short, then I have to `force the transmission`

Is one of this advice correct? I see there are also another parameter of the method Send, which is: `SocketFlags` <= Is there any help of using this `SocketFlags`?

Comment: Is this TCP?  UDP?  Some other protocol?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's common problem with Nagle algorithm that tries to 'glue' data sent together into single packet. It is possible that your code suffers from it as well.

Try to disable it as shown [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.nodelay.aspx) or by setting [`SocketOptionName.NoDelay`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketoptionname.aspx) option with [`SetSocketOption`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e160993d.aspx) method.

Comment: That's probably the issue, but we haven't even been told if it's a TCP socket.

Comment: @Ben Voigt call this 'educated guess', which OP comfirmed =)

Comment: Hi castperOne, Thanks! so if I set: Nodelay=false, the delay will be gone, right? or any other solutions as well, I would be interested to look further.

Comment: @JoesyXHN well, in my experience it helps. Also you may try to reduce [SendBufferSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.sendbuffersize.aspx). If that won't solve your problem, I'd recommend to analyze traffic with [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to find out if problem is at sending or receiving side.

Comment: Hi, I tried to use NoDelay but it does not increase the speed of sending out the data? any suggestion?

Comment: Have you reduced `SendBufferSize` as well? Also, is receiving side code available for modifications? If so, can you disable Nagle's algorithm there as well and reduce `ReceiveBufferSize`. You may also try to switch to async I/O but in my experience it doesn't help for small packets exchange.

Comment: I'm confused by the accepted answer. The last comment by the OP is that it didn't work.