# Socket closes before device gets updated

Tags: c#, sockets, rfid

I'm trying to send some data to an RFID reader to update its status by using a socket.  However, when I try to close the socket properly, the status does not apply on the reader (like a beep or color change).  However, I do get an echo response back from the reader pretty quickly.

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
//send green status
RFIDStatus status = new RFIDStatus();
status.State = RFIDState.Authenticate;
status.Green = RFIDGreen.On;
status.Red = RFIDRed.Off;
status.BeepLength = BeepSound.TwoShort;

string command = string.Format("R1={0} G1={1} S1={2} \r\n", (int)status.Red, (int)status.Green, (int)status.BeepLength);
clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
clientSocket.Connect(remoteEP);

clientSocket.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(command));
int byteRec = clientSocket.Receive(bytes);

Console.WriteLine("Echoed test = {0}", Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, byteRec));

clientSocket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
clientSocket.Close();
```

If I don't close the socket, the RFID reader does update its status properly.  Is there something that I am possibly missing? Setting socket.NoDelay to false does not solve this issue either.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Socket.Send has a delay?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6143291/socket-send-has-a-delay)

Comment: Does it always send you a response? if so, rather than just receive which will collect next to nothing if it hasnt done yet, you could add a bit of a wait in there, or expect to receive a given size response..